# Java expense class

Tags: java, object

I have a question...my professor keeps dancing around.

"The `chooseCategory` method will work with your `setCatNum` setter method. The

`setCatNum` setter method should be as follows:

```
public void setCatNum( ) {
  catNum = chooseCategory( );
}
```

This has a different look than the traditional setter method

`chooseCategory` should print all 6 of your categories, then, using the expense description,

prompt and return the category number. You will need to use Scanner."

Does this mean that they want me to have an object call the `chooseCategory` method, then have the `chooseCategory` method like this:

```
private void chooseCategory() {

    //should print all 6 of your categories, then, using the expense description,
    //prompt and return the category number. You will need to use Scanner.
    System.out.println("Choose a category <number> for " + description);
    for(int i =0; i<categories.length; i++){
        System.out.println(i + " :  " + categories[i]);
        }
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int catUn = userInput.nextInt();
    catNum = catUn;
    System.out.println(catNum);

}
```

With `description` being a private String made at the top.

the UML

Expense

(+) Expense(catNum:int, desc: String, date: SimpleDateFormat, amt: double, repeat: boolean)

(+) Expense(desc: String, date: SimpleDateFormat, amt: double, repeat: boolean)

(-) chooseCategory(): void

***I put the - and + in parenthesis because the code block thinks it needs to be a bullet.

Comment: Ask your professor if you need clarification on your homework. The only thing I can see is that it does say to prompt after you printed the six categories. Also, how is `chooseCategory()` a `void`? They don't return values, yet they are used in a value context within `setCatNum()`.

Comment: I think so, but you need to return the inputted value.

Comment: I have tried asking my professor...they don't answer the question and then gets a lil upset when I continue to ask. Which is why I came on here in hopes somebody would understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I have no idea what your professor wants you to do and I suppose no one on here can tell. Go ask him, if you want to know for sure.

But let me suggest a general approach to improve your code. You should work with return values here.

Implement your class such that:

```
public void setCatNum(int categoryNumber) {
  catNum = categoryNumber;
}

private int chooseCategory() {
  int userSelection = 0;

  // Make user chose a category
  // userSelection = ...

  return userSelection;
}
```

And later you can use the class like this (e.g. in your `main()` method):

```
YourClass yourObject = new YourClass();
yourObject.setCatNum(this.chooseCategory());
```

Here you create a new instance of `YourClass` and *bind* it to the `yourObject` variable. Next, the methods of your object are called (nested calls from inner to outer). First, `chooseCategory()` is executed. The method holds a local `userSelection` variable to store the user's selection (read using the `Scanner`). Finally, the method will return the user selection. The return value is then passed to `setCatNum()` and is available as a method argument here (called `categoryNumber`). Then you can assign the `categoryNumber` to your `catNum` member variable.

---

**// Edit:** Now that you posted your UML:

```
public void setCatNum(int categoryNumber) {
  catNum = categoryNumber;
}

private void chooseCategory() {
  int userSelection = 0;

  // Make user chose a category
  // userSelection = ...

  this.setCatNum(userSelection);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my professor wants chooseCategory() to be a void and not return. This is why I am confused....thank you very much for your explanation tho! You also answered the object question!

Comment: It is impossible to assign ``catNum = chooseCategory()``, if ``chooseCategory()`` is not allowed to return any value (= it is defined ``void``). Maybe that's the lesson your teacher wants you to learn? Otherwise, go ask him again, since it is technically impossible to do so.

Comment: Just read your assignment again, your method is allowed to return a value: "... ``chooseCategory`` should print all 6 of your categories, then, using the expense description, prompt and **return the category number**"

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood your professor and ``setCatNum()`` must be defined ``void``? That's okay in this case.

Comment: Updated my answer, now that you posted UML code. In my third code block, both methods are defined ``void`` (as requested) and category number will be set, when user was prompted.

Comment: I edited it your way and it worked. I will leave comments in my code as of why I did it this way! Thank you so much for your help and quick replies!!

Comment: Have a look at my latest edit, maybe that's what your professor wants. :)

Comment: no...the setCatNum is not what they asked for. "The chooseCategory method will work with your setCatNum setter method. The setCatNum setter method should be as follows:
`public void setCatNum( ) {

catNum = chooseCategory( );
}
This has a different look than the traditional setter method. chooseCategory should print all 6 of your categories, then, using the expense description, prompt and return the category number. You will need to use Scanner.`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning a value in `chooseCategory()` to set to `catNum`. Try something like this:

```
private int chooseCategory() {

    //should print all 6 of your categories, then, using the expense description,
    //prompt and return the category number. You will need to use Scanner.
    System.out.println("Choose a category <number> for " + description);
    for(int i =0; i<categories.length; i++){
        System.out.println(i + " :  " + categories[i]);
    }
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int catUn = userInput.nextInt();
    return catUn;
}
```

Comment: chooseCategory is suppose to be a void. But thank you for the reply!